# Why no UICollectionView equivalent in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicollectionviewlayout

Can someone please explain what the new iOS 13 Collection View Compositional Layout provides that cannot be provided by SwiftUI's declarative API?  Dynamic Layout? Does Diffable Datasource provide something that the Combine framework doesn't?  I could only find one thread in Stackoverflow, but it didn't really go into detail and there was a lot of disagreement.

Comment: SwiftUI does support a ScrollView which you can use to present collections, although you would have to manage your own grids. The GeometryReader method might be helpful, it allows you to easily scale the "cells" to the width and length of the parent view.

Comment: This isn't something we can answer due to the library being developed internally by Apple. Most likely they just weren't able to prioritize it over the more basic views that needed to be built and the bugs that needed to be fixed by release. Or they don't think it's necessary anymore, as it might be coposable from other views.

Comment: SwiftUI does support a Scrollview, but I haven't dug into any limitations.  I know that Apple invested a great deal of money into the Collection View Compositional Layout APIs, so I'm sure they aren't going to say that SwiftUI makes it irrelevant.  But that would explain why they didn't create a UICollectionView equivalent in SwiftUI

Comment: No need to have that. SwiftUI already supports all UIKit elements. Apple may simplify some of them later for direct use, or maybe not!